# 3D Facial Expression Database

Tags: images, 3d, animation, visualization

Can anyone suggest 3D Face Expression Database which has basic expressions like happy, sad, surprise, anger, disgust, ...

I am trying to simulate different expressions on a 2D face image. 
As a start, I am planning to create 3D face templates for each expression and apply texture mapping onto the data.

--Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com/index.html) has pre defined facial expressions and would allow for the other things you want to do.  It is one of the best character tools around (imho).

Also check the site for tutorials as they have some quite comprehensive ones.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want a software. I am trying to build one software like Poser. Any comments on what algorithm/practices/3D models/platform they used?